# What's the traditional way to build a RESTful App via Laravel?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, reactjs, vue.js

I'm going to build my first REST app via Laravel and a client side framework which I'm not sure yet (probably React or Vue.js).

I did some research about how should I build my app, and unfortunately it got me even more confused.

I've come to a conclusion that I can build my app in 2 ways:

- Build the app in the same project. However, without [Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#introduction).
- Separate the App to 2 projects (Front and Back).

---

On the one hand, the pros of building the app on the same project:

- Grants me the option to use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix).
- Laravel offers out of the box [Vue support](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend#writing-javascript).

On the other hand, the pros of building the app separated from Front to Back:

- Each side has its own single responsibility and can be refactored easily.
- As I heard it from my friends, it's more convenient (even tho for me it sounds too complex).

I wanted to know what is the most popular way to build a RESTful app when Laravel is being part of it. Is there another way of what I mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

Personally,

I like to keep them apart because it's easier to maintain. Yes, you have to keep track of 2 different projects/folders/repositories but they are pieces of the same cake.

Scaffolding an API in Laravel is very easy and simple. I assume you already know how to do that. You are worried about loosing the advantages offered by Laravel Mix, but believe me you are loosing nothing.

Since your preference is on Angular, just clone any seed project repository with everything setup. e.g:
1. AngularJS: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
2. Angular 2: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

As you can see, these seed projects already have all the build tools you need and now things seem actually easier. That's what frameworks are made for.

Now imagine later you want to add a mobile app to the stack. You don't even need to change a single thing. Your API already runs independently of the frontend and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Question is opinion based... So here is my opinionated answer.

TLDR: For speed of development and arguably more satisfaction, build as one project. Don't overcomplicate unnecessarily too early. When project gets big enough, and starts to generate you some money, then think about splitting the projects - you will know when it is time.

The Laravel Ecosystem is just great for small, medium and even large applications.

Laravel gives you a resources folder, where you can put all your Javascript & front-end assets. You have Envoy to deploy your application and write your deployment scripts. You have mix to build your assets. You don't have to use mix - you could write your own gulp/webpack/grunt etc...

By keeping together as one project, you are able to use the same IDE project for both front-end and backend work, yet keep separation of concerns because all backend code is completely separated from front-end code. You can tweak the payloads being sent from angular, and tweak how the payloads are handled in PHP api nice and easy so you only need 1 ide and one browser and a terminal client.

The nicest thing about keeping the project together, is that assuming you are using VCS (git) and you really should be, then your front and back-end will always be in-sync with each other. Otherwise, you need to manage & coordinate deployments of your front-end and backend code.

When your application gets big enough, it won't take long to separate the projects as the frontend and backend should be already extremely loosely coupled.

Just think of all the added layers of complexity that you are introducing to your application. When you deploy a change to your REST API, you will probably need to also deploy a change to your angular application. What version of the angular app is compatible with what version of the API? If you have a team of devs, working on specific projects, then this complexity pays off - but most teams have processes in place to manage, synchronise & automate deployments.

Comment: Not *really* opinion-based: having 2 projects means having 2 sets of models, which is more maintenance. The models should not need to be different (and if they are, this just adds more maintenance), so it's unnecessary duplication. The problem of separation is solved simply by using different controllers, which is what MVC is all about. With REST apis, there's simply no "V" part (on the back end)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with 2 projects. I would.

I will give an example using complexity rate of growth. It is just from my own experience. (X means amount of features, Y means how complex they are to implement)

With a single project, it is super simple at first. No communication with the server, no hard stuff, everything is tangled. Then nearing the end, it starts to get harder and harder to create more features/pages because everything is tangled.

Or as a function: 
[image]

But if you start with 2 projects, sure, it will be harder at first (communication, synchronisation, whatever) but the rate of growth for complexity will not be as high. Everything has it's own responsibility, everything does what it needs to do. Tests are simpler, expansion is simpler, refactoring is simpler, and you can complete the project with ease.

Or as a function:
[image]

Clearly, from the graphs above, you can infer that the rate of growth for a single project is much slower. (And of course, not actual numbers, I did not measure anything or tracked such projects, this is just out of my own experience)

Comment: If you separate your front-end and backend project code into 2 separate directories, where is the complexity / coupling between them?

Comment: @Gravy front relies on back, back dictates everything and is pretty much independent. Each project is complex in its own, but the total complexity is less than 1 project